# Collision Detection Logic

Tags: c#, algorithm, xna, collision

I'm creating a 2D platformer with XNA, and it's tilebased and as such will have square and sloped tiles.  My question is, how should my algorithm work?  Right now, I have it to where it separates horizontal and vertical movement, which seems to work well for the square tiles, but it fails in relation to the slopes.  Where should I be checking for slope intersection?

1. Horizontal check, and subsequent repositioning
2. Vertical check, and subsequent repositioning

Where in this algorithm would slopes fall into place?  Or is there another perhaps better solution that I have overlooked which would serve me better?

[EDIT]
Algorithm Pseudocode

```
private void Collision()
{
    if (velocity.X != 0)
    {
        //Check for intersections with new position, reposition if there is an intersection

        //Moving to the right
        if (velocity.X > 0)
        {}

        //Moving to the left
        if (velocity.X < 0)
        {}
    }
    if (velocity.Y != 0)
    {
        //Check for intersections with new position, reposition if there is an intersections

       //Moving downwards
        if (velocity.Y > 0)
        {}

        //Moving upwards
        if (velocity.Y < 0)
        {}
    }
}
```

Comment: You really haven't described your algorithm at all.. can you add more details?

Comment: _"will have square and **sloped tiles**"_ - do you mean square and _triangular corner tiles_?

Comment: Yes, slopes as in those seen in this picture- http://xane.typepad.com/.a/6a013488190c1d970c0148c6fddc57970c-pi